# Why don't we see charts of the colorspace/gamut of a DSLR?

Tags: color, color-spaces, color-gamut

For many displays, we see the color space or gamut shown on chromaticity charts in comparison with some standard color spaces like Rec. 709, sRGB, Adobe RGB, and Prophoto RGB which gives an indication of the display device's color reproduction capability. Similar charts are are also done for many popular printers.

But not for DSLRs, like say the color gamut of a Nikon D300s DSLR plotted on a chromaticity chart? Why is this so?

Comment: Related: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/75517/why-are-the-color-spaces-we-have-access-to-incomplete/75520#75520

Answer (score 6):

The chromatic gamut is the property of output device, not a recording device.

The colorimetric input device is characterised with it's compliance to Maxwell-Ives criterion - i.e. how metamerically close it is to the CIE standard observer - the equivalent of photopic human vision. This compliance can be roughly characterised with one value, the example of it is [DxOMark's metamerism score](http://www.dxomark.com/About/In-depth-measurements/Measurements/Color-sensitivity) and metamerism is the most important property of colour recording device which should be characterised.

Theoretically, a recording device CAN have limited input chromatic gamut if, for example, it uses colour matching functions with negative responses present (I am just making it up because there is no practical possibility of doing this, a device doing this would be a broken device):
[image: CIE1931 CMF]

If it happens so that electronics of that imaginary device are not capable of producing negative image data then wavelengths from 400 to 600 would be out of gamut for such device while some mixtures of wavelengths will be inside of gamut.

However, there is no obligation to use those functions with negative parts because there are completely positive colour matching functions which give accurate metamerism as well because when you have full chromatic data at all image points you can use arithmetic operations on all channels to deduce true colour:
[image: CIE XYZ CMF]

No cameras I've seen have actual negative responses.

The most important thing - metamerism - gets broken in all consumer cameras regardless. You can't deduce true colours from the image data which a usual camera records. Here's an example of trying to deduce true colour from Nikon D70 data taken from http://theory.uchicago.edu/:[image: Nikon D70 CIE best fit]

This graph shows how well colours can be reproduced. Knowing that a CIE XYZ is a space of imaginary super-saturated colours you can see that colour reproduction accuracy is a trainwreck. And to top it off D70 image data gets clipped when transformed to XYZ space - which is in a sense the gamut limitation because XYZ is the widest colour space used after RAW processing.

So, there is no such thing as input gamut in the sense you are asking about.

Comment: > The chromatic gamut is the property of output device, not a recording device

This is incorrect, the gamut is not specifically tied to an output device it can be the colours present in a scene: http://eilv.cie.co.at/term/211

Comment: > it uses colour matching functions with negative responses present

This is again incorrect, the matching functions you have linked are likely Stiles & Burch 1955 2° RGB CMFs r¯(λ),g¯(λ),b¯(λ) and were derived from colour matching experiments on human observers, the negative values are the result of the observers not being able to match the test stimulus with the mixture, thus one of the mixture component is added to the test stimulus and is considered as negative: https://github.com/colour-science/colour-notebooks/blob/master/notebooks/colorimetry/cmfs.ipynb

Comment: It is important to acknowledge that those colour matching functions are not the cones responses of the human visual system nor sensor responses of any kind of capturing device. I think you are confusing too many things here.

Comment: @KelSolaar your reference doesn't say what you think it says.  The gamut of an image is **not** the gamut of the recording device.  A camera's gamut represents the limit of its capability, not the limit of reproducing some simple scene.  Since the full color "palette" represents the neurological response to multiple-wavelength inputs, a digital image merely need match the cones' relative spectral responses.

Comment: @kel-solaar: in practice cameras rarely have input gamut - i.e. the subset of human-visible colours which they can differ between.All cameras, with some rare exceptions, differentiate between every wavelength between 400 and 700.

You are correct in that functions  r¯(λ),g¯(λ),b¯(λ) were derived from experiments - that does not invalidate my statement, they are still valid CMFs which reproduce human metamerism.

I never said that those reponses are human-like, I only said that they are equivalent because they reproduce human metamerism.

That file requires some additional software.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Which reference are you talking about? It is a given that the gamut of a typical image does not represent the full gamut of colours a recording device can capture.

Comment: @EuriPinhollow: My point is that you are taking RGB CMFS derived from psycho-physical experiments (they might actually be Wright & Guild 1931 2° RGB CMFs r¯(λ),g¯(λ),b¯(λ)) saying that they are camera response curves, you then throw the CIE 1931 2° Standard Observer in the middle and try to connect the dots. Camera response curves are related to human visual system as per Maxwell-Ives criterion and somebody with a good knowledge in colour science can understand what you mean, but it is definitely confusing for somebody without that knowledge.

Comment: "kel-solaar: "you then throw the CIE 1931 2° Standard Observer in the middle and try to connect the dots" - connect WHICH dots? You are correct in that my answer is not easily understandable for a beginner. I will probably try to make it more explaining.

Comment: @KelSolaar Wright & Guild CMF and CIE 1931 CMF have equal or almost equal metamerism. CIE 1931 CMF are derived from same kiind of experiment Wright & Guild carried.

Comment: @KelSolaar "saying that they are camera response curves" - I never said that.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that DSLR makers don't provide chromaticity diagrams for their cameras, they usually encode their images using *sRGB* or *Adobe 1998 RGB* colourspaces like @MirekE stated it.

Any colour lying outside those colourspaces gamut is clipped on casual RAW conversion, **even if the camera captured it**. It is also incorrect to think that RAW files don't have a gamut because as per CIE definition the [colour gamut](http://eilv.cie.co.at/term/211) is:

> [...] volume, area, or solid in a colour space, consisting of all those colours that are either:
>
> (a) present in a specific scene, artwork, photograph, photomechanical, or other reproduction;
>   (b) capable of being created using a particular output device and/or medium

Because camera makers don't provide chromaticity diagrams for their DSLR doesn't mean they don't do it for their movie cameras, on those [charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1243.jpg), all the gamuts represented except for the ACES family ones and Pointer are from movie camera vendors (ARRI, Canon, Sony, Panasonic):

[image: ACES Encodings - Diagrams]

If you are interested on how to characterise digital camera and how their colour gamut are computed, Martınez-Verdu et al. in [Concerning the calculation of the color gamut in a digital camera](https://rua.ua.es/dspace/bitstream/10045/973/1/proof_final.pdf) has a lot of relevant information on the topic.

Comment: Can you give the source of those graphs? It looks to me that those triangles are not input gamut but visualisation of output gamut resulting from assuming some primaries during colour conversion.

Comment: Camera sensors simply accumulate charge. Every pixel is just a range of intensity, so a RAW file really doesn't have color per-se, nor does it really have a gamut. The color of the data in a RAW file is entirely a matter of interpretation by processing software. Even if you tag the RAW file with sRGB or AdobeRGB, one is not required to use those color spaces for processing. It's just metadata. The pixel data is limited by noise and the full well capacity of the pixels, and there may be some slight non-linearity in the extremes of the range...but, RAW is RAW.

Comment: The color filter array over the sensor will determine the exact response of each pixel to specific ranges of the spectrum. The curves for any given sensor are going to depend on the specific nature of the color filters and the specific nature of the silicon's response to light. So the sensor itself (not the RAW image file) will have a unique response, however most fall within a given range as unfiltered silicon itself has a fairly consistent response to light, ranging from ~315nm up through ~1100nm, with the response low in UV, growing through the visible spectrum, and peaking in IR.

Comment: So the sensor itself **may** have a gamut (although I don't think that is the correct term...the sensor has a natural **response** to light)...but I don't think it is correct to say that a RAW file has gamut.

Comment: An exposed stock film or a RAW file for what concerns us here does contains colour information about a scene, and it does certainly fit the CIE definition.

Comment: You are using defitinion A but you are ignoring it's scope. The definition A speaks about the variety of colour present in some specific reproduction. Those definitions are specifically constructed to exclude the input gamut definition and you are ignoring it. I am still waiting for you to cite the source of those triangles.

Comment: I honestly think you are reading the definition to suit your view of "gamut", the definition first subject is a scene, the scene being what you are trying to reproduce. I'll let you dig the references from here: https://github.com/colour-science/colour/tree/develop/colour/models/rgb/dataset.

Comment: @kel-solaar: it does not explain why you try to project the definition of gamut of a scene onto the sensor. That link does not explain anything to me, it does not say how the colour space is the gamut of a sensor. The triangles denote the output gamut given some colour conversion, not a gamut of a sensor.

Comment: @EuriPinhollow: Those solids are fitted to encompass the colours that those cameras can faithfully capture without sacrificing data, so they definitely attempt to characterise the capturing (input) capability of those cameras.

Comment: @kel-solaar: "Those solids are fitted to encompass the colours that those cameras can faithfully capture without sacrificing data" - still waiting for the source which claims it.

Comment: Here is some relevant research: [Martínez‐Verdú, F. (2006). Concerning the calculation of the color gamut in a digital camera. Color Research & …, 31(5). doi:10.1002/col.00000](https://rua.ua.es/dspace/bitstream/10045/973/1/proof_final.pdf)

Comment: @kel-solaar: according to [this defifition](http://storage2.static.itmages.ru/i/16/0814/h_1471204498_3130774_d2e3bd3cfc.png) the input gamut always contain all visible colours (because no wavelength produces negative output). What your triangles denotes is "input device plus transform gamut".

Comment: Practically speaking, any unique color that fails to produce a signal greater than the noise floor for a given sensor can be said to be out of the sensor's gamut if the same amount of that color is present in full spectrum white light at an exposure value sufficient to reach full well capacity of R,G, and B sensels.

Answer (score 1):

Cameras can shoot either in RAW, sRGB or AdobeRGB. For sRGB and AdobeRGB the gamut is given. RAW files do not have gamut, you need to convert the image to some color representation like RGB to get gamut and that is a process that happens outside of the camera and the gamut will depend on the editor, profiles and the taste of the person who operates the editor.